# Unlink PHP prermissions denied

Tags: php

I'm having some trouble with the `unlink` function.

I use this to create my directory:

```
$customer_path_files =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/'.$job.'/';
if (!file_exists($customer_path_files)) {

    @mkdir($customer_path_files ,0777,true);


}
```

This works great. The problem is when I try to delete the exact same folder using `unlink`. It says that I don't have permissions to do so.

```
public function deleteFolders($path) {
    $result = FALSE;

    if(file_exists($path)) {
        $result = unlink($path);
    } else {
        $result = true;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Which is the code I'm using to delete the folders and all subfolders but doesn't work. Now, when I create folders manually, `unlink` works perfect under every condition.

I'm running on XAMPP in Windows 8.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, the error is that the Permission is denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`unlink()`](http://php.net/unlink) will remove a file.

If you want to remove a directory, you will need to use [`rmdir()`](http://php.net/rmdir)

```
if (!is_dir('examples')) {
    mkdir('examples');
}

rmdir('examples');
```

Comment: Using rmdir, make sure it is empty or the function will fail too.

Comment: You're absolutely right about that. But if it's not empty, then I'd have to use unlink loop through all the files within it and then re-call the function?

Comment: I actually got it to work with a bit more clever code. Thank you.